# netplan equivalent of ip rule add oif eno5 lookup 5000

Tags: networking, netplan, routing

In a netplan yaml configuration file like this one:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno5:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      link-local: [  ]
      addresses:
      - xxx.xxx.xxx.2/24                     
      # gateway4: xxx.xxx.xxx.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: xxx.xxx.xxx.1
          metric: 500
          table: 5000
      routing-policy:
        - from: 0.0.0.0/0
          interface: eno5
          priority: 501
        - from: xxx.xxx.xxx.2
          table: 5000
          priority: 512
```

I need to manually enter `ip rule add oif eno5 lookup 5000` so that I can do a `ping -I eno5 google.com`.

Please let me know if there is a way to insert this in the yaml file. I have tried the followings to no vail:

```
    - from: 0.0.0.0/0
      interface: eno5
      priority: 501
```

and

```
    - from: 0.0.0.0/0
      oif: eno5
      priority: 501
```